# What did Oliver Wendell Holmes Jr. mean by 'molar to molecular actions'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

<sub>Preface: I originally posted this [on Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/10900/89) but was advised to post here instead.

Secondary Source: *[Introduction to The Study of Law](http://store.thomsonreuters.ca/product-detail/introduction-to-the-study-of-law-8th-edition/)* (8 edn, 2016), p. 11 Middle.

[Primary Source:](https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scc-csc/en/5960/2/document.doc) p 218, writing by Dickson J., *Harrison v. Carswell*, [1976] 2 S.C.R. 200</sub>

> The duty of the Court, as I envisage it, is to proceed in the discharge of its adjudicative function in a reasoned way from principled decision and established concepts. I do not for a moment doubt the power of the Court to act creatively—it has done so on countless occasions; but manifestly one must ask—what are the limits of the judicial function? There are many and varied answers to this question. Holmes J. said in *Southern Pacific Co. v. Jensen*<sup>16</sup>, at p. 221: “I recognize without hesitation that judges do and must legislate, but they can do it only interstitially; they are confined from **molar** to molecular actions”.

Holmes's use of the scientific words 'interstitially' and 'molecular' implies the chemical signification of '[molar](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=molar)', but I don't understand the chemical metaphor here.

Comment: It isn't clear to me, but I suggest that he means "from mass actions to individual actions", a mole being (in a sense) 6 x 10^23 molecules.

Comment: @ColinFine  How would what you say fit into the context of the paragraph? What is a mass action?

Comment: The court's legislative actions must not be on a grand scale; they must be limited to relatively minor "tweaks".

Comment: BTW, this "confined from x to y" locution, meaning "kept or barred from x, only y being allowed or possible", is  old-fashioned. You won't really find it used in contemporary (non-legal) prose.

Comment: @TRomano Interesting meaning. I'm trying to google it but can't find the right search term.

Comment: Hope springs eternal in the human breast;
Man never is, but always to be blessed:
The soul, uneasy and confined from home,
Rests and expatiates in a life to come.

Comment: Ha, just seeing this comment now, @Tᴚoɯɐuo. (Had to look up "expatiate.")

Comment: We can see that this phrase, **from molar to molecular**, was a commonplace in the early decades of the 20th century.  It meant something like "from macro to micro".  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22molar+to+molecular%22&num=20&lr=lang_en&newwindow=1&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F1935&tbm=bks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretentious language which Oliver Wendell Holmes can only have used to try to impressed others with his intelligence. The words are used in very nonstandard ways.

Since I am a chemist, I'll agree that there are three words related to chemistry.

If a chemist uses the word "interstitial" then it means the spaces between atoms in a crystal. Think of atoms as balls and stacking them carefully in a  pattern in a box. The small spaces left between the balls are the "interstitial spaces."

A mole is 6.023 X 10^23 (think billions of billions of billions) molecules of a substance. "Molar" is the adjective form as has been pointed out.

A molecule is the smallest chemical unit that is a particular thing. So one molecule of table sugar is the smallest piece (i.e. one chemical unit) of table sugar that you can get.

So the whole phrasing means that actions can't be taken on a grand scale but only on a small scale. To make a different analogy, try shaking hands with a million people at the  same time. It is traditional to shake with only the right hand, so you can only shake one other hand at a time.

I have been always impressed with William F. Buckley's mastery of language which allowed him to use the right words to express an idea with exactly the right connotations. This just isn't that sort of language use. You'd have to understand chemistry to parse these words of Oliver Wendell Holmes, but even  as a chemist I find the phrasing so odd that I believe it is absolutely pretentious.

Comment: Curious to call someone from 200 years ago "pretentious." That's how people wrote back then -- especially learned lawmakers like Oliver Wendell Holmes.

Answer (score 1):

What impresses me about the answers and the comments is that no one seems to have bothered to read the actual decision.

It is a dissent. The intended audience was a tiny group of current and future Supreme Court judges, who can be presumed to be well educated and intelligent people with access to a dictionary. And it is quite clear that the two dissenting justices were angry with their colleagues' narrow mindedness. The case involved whether the state of New York's workmens' compensation law protected the widow and children aged 7 and 3 of a stevedore who was killed working on a gangplank over the Hudson River. The Supreme Court ruled that the widow and children were not protected because the gangplank extended above federal waters, and admiralty law is the exclusive province of the federal government. Holmes disagreed.

The **molar** versus **molecular** comparison was to distinguish between the relatively huge and the relatively tiny. Permitting New York State to protect stevedores working on ships at berth through a workmens' compensation law was not, in Holmes' view, threatening federal control over admiralty law. It operated to fill a lacuna in the ancient law of admiralty. The chemical metaphor is perfectly apt except for the unfortunate use of **interstitial**, which has a technical meaning in chemistry as well as a general meaning not tied to crystals. The meaning of the metaphor was elucidated by the immediately following discussion of specific cases involving the interplay between admiralty and state law, none of which were quoted in the OP.

This was an extremely brief quotation from a judicial opinion directed from one judge to other judges. I agree it makes no sense if treated as a statement in chemistry. But the distinction in magnitude being made, between general control over vessels navigating the high seas or the lakes and rivers of the US and provision for protecting workers killed or injured on the New York City docks, is very great. You can accuse Holmes of engaging in hyperbole in likening it to the difference in magnitude between 6 * 10^23 and 1, but it is perfectly clear in context.

LATE EDIT: You can find the complete decision of the Supreme Court by going to wikipedia's entry on Southern Pacific v. Jensen, which has a link to decision and dissents at the very end of the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

A *mole* is a large number of molecules, but both are relatively small in mass compared to things in life on our scale. *Molar* is an adjective for *mole*. J. Holmes is saying that judges legislate, but it is only "interstitially," meaning only between doing other more important duties of theirs.

So when he says they legislate "from molar to molecular," it's just a colorful way of saying "from small to tiny."

Comment: I don't know that a mole is "very small in mass compared to things in life on our scale."  For instance, a mole of salt would be about two ounces of it, which is more than you're supposed to eat in a month.

Comment: (And while it's maybe not standard to talk about things this way, a mole of gold atoms would be about six and a half troy ounces -- currently over $8,000 worth.)

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Good point. I still think it's a relatively small thing. I think the author meant to express "from small to tiny." I'll change my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Ringo No, he meant to compare the relatively large to the tiny.  The ratio of molecules in a mole to one molecule is about 6 * 10^23 to 1. The relative numbers are of astronomically different magnitudes.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I don't disagree necessarily, but are you saying the phrase just means "from large to small"? Well that's a fancy way of saying not much at all.

Comment: @Ringo As I say in my more detailed answer, he is saying that judges must not act as legislators on very large issues, but may and often do act as legislators on very small issues. It is not inclusive, but comparative. It is a metaphor and hyperbole. The problem is that without reading the case it is impossible to get the context. I have tried to summarize the gist of the case in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the obligatory and traditional online caveat IANAL (I Am Not A Lawyer).

The language is (probably deiberately) quite obtuse.

Working through the key parts:

> I recognize without hesitation that judges do and must legislate

No problem there, judges have a key role in the law-making process

> but they can do it only interstitially

Interstice *n* is the space within a body of some type. From the OED:

> An intervening space (usually, empty); esp. a relatively small or narrow space, between things or the parts of a body (freq. in pl., the minute spaces between the ultimate parts of matter); a narrow opening, chink, or crevice.

In this case the body is legislation. The speaker is saying that judges cannot make new law - they are limited to interpreting and fine-tuning legislation that has been passed by government. they are, therefore, working interstitially.

> they are confined from molar to molecular actions

I suspect that the OP has misinterpreted the intended use of molar, in this case I doubt that any metaphor was intended - there is a, rarely used, meaning for molar (again, from the OED):

> Of or relating to mass; acting on or by means of large masses of matter. Often contrasted with molecular

So, my interpretation is that it is being pointed out that judges may only make relatively minor (molecular) changes rather than the large (molar) ones.

At a guess, the lawyer is arguing that that finding against their client would require a decision that would exceed the authority of the bench?

**EDIT**
It's just occurred to me that a more widely used contrast (at least in my day job) is 'Macro to Micro' - very similar in meaning but a little less pretentious in usage

Comment: Ianal, too. And I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: I think it may be part of our job specification

Answer (score -1):

I think that interstitial is plain enough: rulings work in the interstices in the legislative record (between laws, between different sections of one law, etc.). 
I think molecular is also clear - that which affects a single individual or unique context. 
There are, I think, two problems with interpretation. One is what is meant by the word "molar", but the more important one is what is meant by "confined from molar to molecular". I think even if you answer the first, the second remains unclear.
The two possibilities for the meaning of molar (in crude form) are "modest" or "large". But does 'confined from' mean 'restricted away from' or 'restricted to in between'? Without more understanding of his language and that of his social-professional era, I'm sure no single meaning will be obtained. I'll also point out that it may not be SIZE of the action he was thinking about, it may be precision - as in from crude or blunt to very precise and surgical.